# How to calculate this two port network impedance of this circuit?

Tags: passive-networks

This is the schematic from [youtube link](https://youtu.be/Aa1A8zLAvbw).

[image]

Here is how I analyse this circuit.

[image]

$$I_1 + 6 (I_1 - I_x) = V_1 \tag{1}$$
$$2 (I_2 + I_x) = V_2 \tag{2}$$

And to calculate \$I_x\$, we have

$$6 (I_1 - I_x) = 4 I_x + 2 (I_2 + I_x) $$
$$\Rightarrow I_x = \frac{3 I_1 + I_2} {6} $$

Substitute \$ \mbox{$\Large \frac{3 I_1 + I_2} {6} $}\$ for \$I_x \$ in equations (1) and (2).

$$\Rightarrow 4 I_1 - I_2 = V_1 $$
$$\Rightarrow I_1 + \frac{7} {3} I_2 = V_2 $$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & -1 \\
1 & \frac{7} {3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

However, this youtuber give the following

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 1 \\
1 & 1.6
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Who is correct?

Comment: Specifically what are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Andyaka Impedance network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither ok ...

Correct \$ Ix= I1/2 - I2/6 \$

Solution is :
\$ 4 * I1 + I2 = V1 \$ and ...
\$  I1 + 5/3 * I2 = V2 \$

\$1.6\$ is just a "simplified" \$5/3\$ ...

Answer (score 1):

You have a sign error where you calculated

$$I_x= \frac{1}{2} \cdot I_1 -  \frac{1}{6} \cdot I_2 $$

So in order to make this answer useful not only for finding these specific error but for general use:

When you want to verify a result: Compute it by a different method (as not to make the same error twice).

E.g: In this case what you could use is the method of **superposition**:

You set $$ I_1 = 0$$
And then only calculate the voltages that are generated by the current I2.

And then you do the same thing the other way around.

(In your case: since your solution only differs by the influence of I2 then you would have found the error right there).

And with this method you can directly read off your matrix elements.